# Image loading issue for different resolutions for XXXHDPI devices

Tags: android, image, android-drawable

I have added one splash screen image(1440 X 2560) in background. When I run the app, I see the image as stretched for the Samsung S8(All xxx devices).

- Samsung Galaxy S7 resolution: 1440 x 2560 - XXXHDPI
- Samsung Galaxy S8 resolution: 1440 x 2960 - XXXHDPI

The issue is if I am adding image(1440 X 2960) in a drawable-xxxhdpi folder, then image will be compressed for Samsung S7, and if I am adding image(1440 X 2560) in a drawable-xxxhdpi folder, the things will be bad in Samsung S8 device.

Is there any way through which we can manage the different images in our resources folder for different XXXHDPI devices?

Comment: android will manage different image sizes on different screens/devices once you have put all the different sizes in the correct folders... this is the reason why there are _drawable-xxxhdpi_ etc

Comment: @B001ᛦ Please refer below web page which says that 1440 X 2560 and 1440 X 2960 both are XXXHDPI device, so how OS will be manage my image, will it not be stretched according to you?

Reference Page: https://material.io/tools/devices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my way and it worked, try to create a drawable-long-xxxhdpi folder in res and put the 1440x2960 pixel image there. Hopefully can

Comment: This can be posted as a comment, please check [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)